# In terraform how to set a new path mapping for an app service in azure?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azureportal

In azure when i go to an App Service -> Settings -> Configuration -> Path mappings i see the following:

[image]

Now let's suppose i want to add more path mappings to it how can i do it, **without** using App service slots, how can we implement something like this with terraform?
example of what i pretend:
[image]

I found an github answer from the terraform providers that involved an azure template deploy using App Service Slots.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1422

Anyone found a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not yet possible in Terraform. According to [this post on GitHub](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3752#issuecomment-704283331), you can add more path mappings via a PowerShell script once Terraform has finished provisioning its resources.